# actionscript classes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

ok here my problem
i have created a fla file called alarmclock.fla
and an as file called alarmclock.as

however i want to use the as file in another fla file called mycoursework.fla

is this possible?

i have tried to do this by linking an object (movieclip) on mycoursework.fla to alarmclock.as but error 1120 comes up acces of undefined property clock_txt and various others too. But* i have already create an instance name for clock_txt.

do i have to create var again in the fla file?
or is it because i hav linked it to an object?

what do i do?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do : - to import the class alarmclock, or to import the whole result swc on the stage and access the methods of alarmclock ?

Comment: to import class alarmclock.as to mycoursework.fla so it would wrk as it was on alarmclock.fla

Comment: and do i have by anychance have to use scope?

Answer (score 0):

just copy the as file, rename the package if needed, and link it in the fla (as document class in properties panel)

Comment: Please don't do this, for any language, ever.  It's ghetto, makes code maintenance a nightmare, and would certainly make code reviewers in a professional work environment question how you were ever employed.

Comment: yes, you're right, thats how nasa blew up a space shuttle. I just assumed by the rank of the user that its probably needed for the school, because the professor didn't explained it well.. (I'm a bit fed up by the newbie questions this weekend, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

Each one of your document classes needs to inherit from `AlarmClock.as`.  However, since this essentially makes the AlarmClock the document class, AlarmClock needs to extend `Sprite`.

Example:

**AlarmClock.as** (Shared document class)

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    //Class
    public class AlarmClock extends Sprite
    {
        //Constructor
        public function AlarmClock(message:String)
        {
            trace(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**DocumentA.fla with DocumentA.as as Document Class**

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import AlarmClock;

    //Class
    public class DocumentA extends AlarmClock
    {
        //Constructor
        public function DocumentA()
        {
            super("Called From DocumentA");
        }
    }
}
```

**DocumentB.fla with DocumentB.as as Document Class**

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import AlarmClock;

    //Class
    public class DocumentB extends AlarmClock
    {
        //Constructor
        public function DocumentB()
        {
            super("Called From DocumentB");
        }
    }
}
```

More here:  [Inheritance (object-oriented programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29)